# How do you convert a string to a long so it can be used to read binary bytes in C#?

Tags: c#

So my project is to pull the offset from an ini file. The keyName is the offset. The keyValue contains the items to display. I'm getting an error when trying to convert the string to a long when reading the keyName from the ini.

Error: 
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Number.StringToNumber(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, ref System.Number.NumberBuffer, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo, bool)
    System.Number.ParseInt64(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)
    long.Parse(string)
    CSOTN.CSOTN.BLoad_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
    System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs)
    System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons, int)
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]

```
                        //Test String
                        string teststring = "0x2253";

                        long offset = long.Parse(teststring);


                        br.BaseStream.Position = offset;
                        itemvalues = br.ReadByte().ToString("X2");

                        //Test output
                        Messagebox.Show(itemvalues)
```

Comment: It would help if you included the actual exception message. You started after that, with the call stack.

Comment: Like:

https://pastebin.com/f75c8HsK

Comment: A link to an image isn't helpful, especially when it's buried in a comment. Error messages are text, and if you can copy/paste the callstack you can copy/paste the exception message, and [edit] your post to put it where it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Convert.ToInt64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint64?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt64_System_String_System_Int32_) has an overload that lets you convert text from different bases.

In this case, since your string starts with `0x`, it's likely hexadecimal, or base-16.

You can therefore parse it simply like this:

```cs
Convert.ToInt64("0x2253", 16)
```